# Files not loading properly when opening from an app'

Tags: 20.04, error-handling

files are not loading correctly on ubuntu 20.04 when opening some apps that require to use the files directory

[files opened from bekeper (database app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w59md.png)

Comment: What do you mean "files"? Looks like a font problem. Is it a snap app? Try using the deb

Comment: I mean File manager. In some apps when is necessary to open the file manager from them, happens what is on the image

Comment: Please add `sudo fc-cache --force --verbose` to your question?